# R - servr::jekyll() build error

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr

I am trying to use `jekyll` with `knitr` as proposed here

https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll

When I try to use the `R function` (through R Studio)

```
servr::jekyll()
```

I get an error

```
sh: jekyll: command not found
Error in jekyll_build() : Failed to run: jekyll build
```

There is no problem when building the `github` example, it works fine. 
I have no idea where the error could come from.

I work on a mac `OS X Yosemite`.

Any clue ?

Comment: A `[sudo] gem install jekyll` seems to be in order from that error message. That could take a while and you may need to `brew install ruby` first.

Comment: `jekyll` is working fine - it is when I try to use it inside `RStudio`. Thanks

Comment: That helps (you did not mention RStudio in your question). With recent OS X releases, RStudio is often hampered by environment variables not being passed. See if explicitly entering a `PATH` (e.g. `PATH=/path/to/bin;/path/to/other/bin open -a RStudio` helps

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar how to set up path. I think the issue has to do with the `servr` package directly.

Comment: You can print out `Sys.getenv('PATH')` and `Sys.which('jekyll')` in the R console of RStudio. My guess is that you need to upgrade RStudio. There was indeed a PATH issue after Yosemite was released, but we have fixed it immediately.

Comment: The result from `Sys.getenv('PATH')` is  `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"` and `Sys.which('jekyll')` is `jekyll ""`. I will try to upgrade my `RStudio` and see if it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just updated RStudio `R version 3.1.2` - `Sys.getenv('PATH')` is still `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin"` - any clue ? thanks again

Comment: @Yihui - I tried again to build but still the same error. It is strange because `servr::serve_example("rmd", servr::rmdv1)` works. Do you have any idea what I could try ?

Comment: In the terminal, see what `which jekyll` returns. Which RStudio are you using? And can you upgrade R to the latest version as well?

Comment: @Yihui - Regarding the `which jekyll` I have : `/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll`. I just upgraded R and re-installed `knitr` and `servr` but unfortunately I still get the same error message `> servr::jekyll()
sh: jekyll: command not found. The RStudio version is `Version 0.99.447`. Any more clue ? I am really motivate to build a website with your `jekyll-knitr`. 
Error in jekyll_build() : Failed to run: jekyll build`.

Comment: @Yihui - the function `rmdv1()` works however. How could I use it to generate my `Rmd` file ? Then I guess I would have to drag the files manually.

Comment: `rmdv1()` does not rely on system software packages like Jekyll. I guess your problem is easier to solve if the Jekyll executable is in a "standard" path, e.g. you can make a symlink from `.rvm/gems/..../jekyll` to `/usr/local/bin`. In fact I installed everything using Homebrew, including Jekyll, so I rarely have to worry about PATH issues.

Comment: @Yihui Thank you. I did not know I could install Jekyll with Homebrew. When I try I get `Error: No available formula for jekyll `. I guess it is a mac problem. I tried the symlink solution but now I get an Ruby error `env: ruby_executable_hooks:`. I will try to solve this problem now ! Anyway if you have other solution than using `jekyll()` I am still very motivate to build a website with `Rmd`. Do you have a link for a *manual* way to do it ? Btw I really appreciate all your work ! Amazing job.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I installed jekyll from Homebrew, but it was not true. I rarely use Mac and my memory was wrong. However, I just checked it and found my jekyll was under /usr/bin/ (I believe I did `sudo gem install jekyll`). It might be because you were using rvm to manage gems. Anyway, I believe you can just provide the full path to the jekyll executable in `servr::jekyll()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the full path of the executable `jekyll` to the `servr::jekyll()` function (which can be found via `which jekyll` in the terminal), e.g.

```
servr::jekyll(command = '/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/jekyll build')
```

Comment: Perfect ! It is working !!! Just a small but **important point** : instead of `servr::jekyll(command = '/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/jekyll build')`, you should change `bin` by `wrappers` in order to get `servr::jekyll(command = '/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/jekyll build')` ! Now it is working ! Thank again !

Comment: Does anyone know why `wrappers` is necessary?

Comment: I got an error when I run it: servr::jekyll(command = '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/jekyll build')
/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory
Error in jekyll_build() : 
  Failed to run: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/jekyll build